# Prototype Traversing

Tags: prototypejs, dom-traversal

I have a series of div's with assigned class 'steps', each div is separated by a `<hr />` element. Each `div` contains distinct text.

I need to traverse, using prototype, to a specific `hr` which has a `div` with certain text.

For e.g. I need reference to `<hr />` that is above `div` containing `jkl`

```
<div class="content">abc</div>
<hr />
<div class="content">def</div>
<hr />
<div class="content">ghi</div>
<hr />
<div class="content">jkl</div>
<hr />
<div class="content">mno</div>
<hr />
<div class="content">pqr</div>
```

I reckon, we need to first find reference to the `div`, this can be achieved using the following selector:

```
$$('div.content:contains("jkl")')
```

But the `:contains` selector is only supported in v1.7, and I have v1.6 at disposal, that doesn't identify the selector.

Looking forward to a push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have 1.7 available you can try this - I don't like doing this but it will work.

```
$$('div.content').each(function(div){
    if(div.innerHTML.include('jkl'))
    {
       //Do something here
    }
});
```

here is a jsfiddle of the HTML with this snippet of code http://jsfiddle.net/jwestbrook/zdvyD/

Comment: I hate this too, as it could slow down when there are loads of divs to iterate, but I guess its the only way out, Thanks

Comment: `$$(".content")` may be slightly faster than `$$("div.content")`. Also previous `hr` may be retrieved e.g. with `div.previous()` or `div.previous("hr")`.